# Find parent and ancestor elements from the current element

Tags: java, xpath, appium

I am using java bindings for appium. I have WebElement object of the current element. From the current element how will I find its parent and ancestors element obj.

Comment: Create Xpath using parent and ancestors keyword to find corresponding name

Comment: Can you tell me how i mean syntax? I tried ::ancestors && .//../ this did not work.

Comment: This topic might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276602/appium-android-finding-element-inside-another-element

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code, you can try with you element details:

```
//*[@accessibility-id='element']/parent::input
//*[@accessibility-id='element']/ancestor::input
```

Let me know if you see issue